# Power BI Desktop - Storing credentials

Tags: rest, access-token, powerbi-desktop

I am fetching POWER BI admin and workspace information using the Power BI Rest API from the power BI Desktop which I plan to publish as a report later. I have written a function in Power Bi query editor to generate an access token which I am calling in my REST API call. All this works fine. But, how can I secure my function to generate access token. Currently, the username and password are being hardcoded in the function.

What is the best practice and how to make this more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a similar problem a while ago and found the best solution to be using this Power BI REST API Connector:

Article describing the connector: https://www.thepoweruser.com/2021/02/21/power-bi-rest-api-connector/

Github: https://github.com/migueesc123/PowerBIRESTAPI

Comment: Thanks a lot Emill.. This is great. It worked for me. Just another question, how do we share the MEZ file generated. Meaning, do we check in the project to source control.

Comment: I am having trouble when viewing the reports in Power BI service. I get the following error:

Comment: Unable to refresh the model (id=xxxxxx) because it references an unsupported data source

Comment: In order to refresh the report you must use the MEZ file in your data gateway. We use an On-Premise gateway.
There is another article for this: https://www.thepoweruser.com/2018/04/23/refreshing-a-power-bi-custom-connector-in-the-cloud/

If you are looking for activity events, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/get-activity-events) - note that no matter the call you make, it will only retrieve the latest month of activity. For this case, we use incremental refresh as a "hack" to store activity data for longer than a month. (Requires Premium or PPU workspace)